# Best recording device for acoustic guitar and voice

Tags: voice, acoustic-guitar, recording, live

I have a couple of live concert consisting of an acoustic guitar and a singer that need to be recorded.

One is totally unplugged, and the other has both musicians plugged through an acoustic amp that has a line out to direct record.

Is there a decent recording device I can buy that allows me to record in both situations considering my budget is about 100$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100$ is a bit low, but look for a used Zoom H2? (H2N currently goes at about 150€ now so might be possible. H2 is just as good and I've seen them on ebay for about 70$US.)

Otherwise, smartphones make pretty decent portable recorders now. I use an app called Voice Recorder which is free for general stuff. It's quite OK.

In this scenario once you have a decent mic (most smartphones are acceptable) mic position is most of the battle to getting an acceptable recording. The Zoom has the advantage though of manual setting of recording level,m which is a big help.